# How does the MAD (Multiply, Add, Divide) Hashing function work?

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

I have been assigned as a university project the task to create data structures (such as minheap, hashtable etc.) from scratch. However the Hashtable or more specifically the Hash maps - functions have given me quite some trouble. I have come across the MAD (Multiply, Add, Divide) function which basically is: h(x) = [(a*x + b) % p] % N, where a,b : random integers, p : large prime number and N : number of elements in hashtable.

My question is how (and why) exactly does this function distribute evenly the values in the hashtable.

Comment: Who said it does? Btw this seem to be math question rather than programming.

Comment: Well I am new to stack overflow and here seemed the better place to ask the question since it is related to data structures, however I see where you are coming from since it has a math aspect to it. Anyway I also think it does not work as efficiently, however it is what our professor suggested we use.

Comment: _I have come across the MAD function_ Do you have a link to this you can [edit] into your question?

Comment: I did not understand what should I edit into the question?

Comment: Where did you come across that description?  If we can read the same source we can better explain what works (or doesn't) with it.

Comment: I found it in a book which is unfortunately in Greek, and also our professor in class said it could be a possible solution. I also found a thread in here somewhat related to it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017108/mad-method-compression-function) but it didn't help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `h(x) = [(a*x + b) % p] % N`

Let's look at `a*x + b` in isolation first.  If you imagine `a` broken down into a sum of powers of two, `a*x` is then the sum of `x` bit shifted left by a smattering of powers of two, such that each bit in `x` impacts other bit positions that are set in `a`, and some further bits when the summation produces carries at particular bits.  Adding `b` mixes in another set of random bits: much like XORing would, but with some extra complexity from the carries.  If say `x` has is a value between 0 and 255, with bits `abcdefgh` (each being 0 or 1), then so far we've got:

```
         (a&1 ? abcdefgh : 0) +
        (a&2 ? abcdefgh0 : 0) +
       (a&4 ? abcdefgh00 : 0) +
      (a&8 ? abcdefgh000 : 0) +
                     ...      +  // continues for a&16, a&32 etc.
        ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP         // however many random bits in "b"
```

So, in the "1s" column we're summing `h` and `P`, which might carry into the "2s" column with `g`, `h` and `O`, and on it goes.

If `a` is say 37, which is 32+4+1, then we're adding `x` itself, `x << 2`, and `x << 5`: each bit in `x` thereby impacts more bits in the hash value (this is good, indeed with a cryptographic-strength hash function, changing any bits in the key - whether a single bit, half or all of them - should pretty much randomly flip about half the bits in the hash value).

Returning to the full formula, let's imagine we skipped the `% p` and had just `% N`, but the current table size is a power of two: `% N` is then equivalent to a bitwise-AND operation for some number of less-significant bits.  Put another way, it's throwing away a lot of the randomness we've built up in the more significant bits of our `a * x + b` calculation.  So, to make the hash function safe to use with any number of buckets, we can introduce `% p` first, which means if there are patterns in the hash value related to power-of-two positions from the summation step, they're effectively scattered across random positions in the 0..p range.

Consider say a hash between 0 and 255 - if `N` was 200, we'd be twice as likely to  hash to a bucket in the 0..55 range.  To make this effect less significant, we want the hash value to have many more bits than the MOD value, and this principle applies in a layered way to the values we should choose for `p` and `N`:

- `a * x + b` values should tend to be significantly larger than `p`, and be spread across a range much larger than `p`, so `% p` separates them more across the buckets, but
- `p` should be much larger than `N`, so we don't have low-indexed buckets with significantly higher collision probabilities (which is especially bad if you're using linear probing to resolve collisions).

For example, if we wanted to support values of `N` up to 2<sup>24</sup>, and we're doing these calculations with 32 bit unsigned integers so `a` and `b` have random values in that range, we might split the difference pick a prime around about 2<sup>28</sup>.